# Does iOS/UIKit have built in support for scheduling scroll like dinging

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to implement an action that when I press and hold begins to repeatedly do an action (similar to a scroll button on a Desktop UI). Is there first class support for this in the UIGestureRecognizer/events framework, or do I just roll my own?

E.g.

```
var timer:Timer?

func killDing() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.timer = nil
}

func startDing() {
    self.killTimer()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) {
        self.ding() // this is where the repeated code happens
    }
}

override func beginTracking(_ touch:UITouch, with event:UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    self.startDing()
}

override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.endTracking(touch, with: event)
    self.killDing()
}
```

I can of course do this with a LongPressGestureRecognizer as well. My question is whether I need to roll my own ding loop as shown above, or if there's something more first class in UIKit that I'm currently not aware of and should be taking advantage of.

Comment: Using a timer with a long press gesture would work. There's nothing built-in a gesture that can be setup to "ding" regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right way. You can use use timers to repeat some actions, but you should [add](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418468-add) [the created timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091888-init) into a run loop  with a [`common`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/mode/1408609-common) mode, without this mode, the run loop will not call the timer's action while a user is touching the screen

```
let timer = Timer(timerInterval: interval, repeats: true, block: block) 
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: . common)
```

Also you can use [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink), to call your action. You can find example of using CADisplayLink in [my library](https://github.com/K-Be/RAVAnimator), witch can help to you implement animation based on CADisplayLink:

```
let link = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateAction(sender:)));
link.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .commonModes);
```